# Sorting Strings and Structures alphabetically in C

Tags: c, string, sorting, structure

I am trying to write a Function that takes a set of strings from a structure and organizes the structure alphabetically. Here is what I have so far:

```
// Preconditions: array of structure "Shift"
// integer value indicating number of shifts
// Postconditions: none - this function does not return anything.
// Actions: Sort the shifts by the TA's first name.

void sort_data(struct Shift shift_data[], int *num_shifts)
{
int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<num_shifts; i++)
        for (j=0; j<num_shifts; j++)
        {
        if (strcmp(shift_data[i+1].name, shift_data[i].name) < 0)
              {
                  temp[i]=shift_data[i];
                  shift_data[i]=shift_data[i+1];
                  shift_data[i]=temp[i];
              }

        }


}
```

I am not sure if I need a nested loop or not. I am sure that num_shifts and shift data is being read and pointed to correctly. I also declared my structure and structure related variables  at the top of my code as such:

```
struct Shift
{
char name[100];
char day_of_week[100];
int start_hour;
int end_hour;
};

struct Shift shift_data[100];
struct Shift temp[100];
```

Sorry for not stating this but I NEED to use these three functions:

```
int read_data(struct Shift shift_data[], int *num_shifts);
void sort_data(struct Shift shift_data[], int *num_shifts);
void print_data(struct Shift shift[], int *num_shifts);
```

I can add others but it is not needed.

I need to figure out how I would sort the structure with respect to a string type in that function that is stored in shift_data[i].name

Thank you for your help in advance

This is what the finished sort function looks like:

```
// Preconditions: array of structure "Shift"
// integer value indicating number of shifts
// Postconditions: none - this function does not return anything.
// Actions: Sort the shifts by the TA's first name.

void sort_data(struct Shift shift_data[], int *num_shifts)
{
    int i, changed;
    do
    {
        changed = 0;
        for (i=0; i < (*num_shifts) - 1; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(shift_data[i].name, shift_data[i+1].name) > 0)
            {
                memcpy(&temp, shift_data + i, sizeof (struct Shift));
                memcpy(shift_data + i, shift_data + i + 1, sizeof (struct Shift));
                memcpy(shift_data + i + 1, &temp, sizeof (struct Shift));
                changed = 1;
           }
        }
    } while (changed != 0);
}
```

Thank you everyone for your help

Comment: You fail to actually state a question that can be answered..

Comment: I can't use strcpy because I am trying to sort the entire structure

Comment: What do you mean? How can I rephrase what I've said?

Comment: Why an `int *num_shifts`?  Is the function going to change the number of shifts recorded?  And your code shouldn't be compiling without loud complaints from the compiler, if it compiles at all.  You need `*num_shifts` if it is a pointer.  Or you need to drop the `*` in the parameter list — the most plausible solution.

Comment: How about writing a compare function and call `qsort()`?

Comment: You need to review your loops and comparisons.  The outer loop is OK (could go to `num_shifts - 1` but no harm done as written).  The inner loop should go from `i + 1` to `< num_shifts`.  And you should compare and swap elements `[i]` and `[j]` — not `[i]` and `[i+1]`.

Comment: num_shifts is the amount of strings i will need to sort, it is read in in another function and stored in main.

Comment: This assignment requires i use certain predetermined functions.

Comment: @all: William is writing an implementation of Bubble Sort; a common exercise. Please try to concentrate on helping him.

Comment: @WilliamPhence Append requirements like "his assignment requires i use certain predetermined functions." to the post - and list the functions.

Comment: You have to use those three functions. Which of those are given and which you have to implement. My guess (according to your question) is to implement the `sort_data` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very basic bubble sort, very inefficient compared to more advanced sorting algorithms, and still copies the whole structure around instead of pointers, but it is closer than what you started with:

```
struct Shift shift_data[100];
struct Shift temp;

void sort_data(struct Shift shift_data[], int *num_shifts)
{
    int i, changed;
    do
    {
        changed = 0;
        for (i=0; i < (*num_shifts) - 1; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(shift_data[i].name, shift_data[i+1].name) > 0)
            {
                memcpy(&temp, shift_data + i, sizeof (struct Shift));
                memcpy(shift_data + i, shift_data + i + 1, sizeof (struct Shift));
                memcpy(shift_data + i + 1, &temp, sizeof (struct Shift));
                changed = 1;
           }
        }
    } while (changed != 0);
}
```

The basic idea is that it scans through the array, comparing each item with the next. Every time it notices one out of order it swaps them. Over subsequent passes the items that should be at the front float to the front like 'bubbles', and the same for items that should be at the back. The function keeps a variable `changed` to determine whether any change was made on the last pass through the array- when it goes through the whole array without changing anything, the loop can exit because the array is sorted.

Note that as you are passing in a pointer`int *num_shifts`, you need to dereference it with `*num_shifts` to access the `int` that it points to.

You didn't really need to mention the `read_data()` and `print_data()` functions, they are nothing to do with sorting, which was what you asked about.

Also surely one of the `// Postconditions:` for your function is that the array is sorted?

Comment: Yes that is the postcondition. I am trying your code now I am getting a compiler error saying: " 'Shift' undeclared (first use in this function)"


Also should it be while (changed == 0 )

Comment: I made a correction, the way your struct is declared it had to be referred to as `struct Shift` of course. Also you want the loop to continue if `changed != 0`, because that means that something changed on the last pass and the loop is not sorted. I made that more explicit.

Comment: This works but puts it in the reverse order hmmmm

Comment: OK well the test that compares the result of `strcmp()` should be `> 0` instead of `< 0`, that makes sense actually ;) If the result is `< 0`, then the first string is less than the second, which in this case indicates that they are in the correct order.

Comment: I think we are getting closer, this sorts it but leaves out the last one and places a blank on in it;s place at the very top of the print....

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't your printing code?

Comment: I don't see why it would. It prints out the new struct shift_data in order from 0 to num_shifts-1

Comment: I made sure everything was good before I started the sort function.

Also when I use your (*num_shifts)-1 it compiles but crashes when I input the file name

Comment: Sorry no idea why your code is crashing as I can't see it. The code I gave you works fine: http://codepad.org/qjx3fDQH

Comment: with this http://codepad.org/cevIbgq1  it properly sorts it out but the segmentation error causes the output to print out much more unneeded info

Comment: got it with this:  http://codepad.org/cevIbgq1

Thank you so much for your help Galax much appreciation from my side!!

Comment: It runs fine even when I alter the input file. I'll have to take a look at it tomorrow when my eyes aren't dead. have a great one Galax and those who tried to help me GN

Comment: Good luck. Maybe you posted the wrong link last time- the "segmentation error" and "got it with this" links were the same.

Comment: I think the Segmentation error might be because there is no one inputting the input file's name and there is no infile.

Comment: Aah yeah, you can't really test the reading of a file with those online IDEs, you could build the data instead of reading it as I did here: http://codepad.org/qjx3fDQH - make 100% sure your function signatures match the way that you call them e.g. if your function takes an `int *`, call it with `&my_int_var` and if it takes an `int`, call it with `my_int_var`. The fact that an `int` can be automatically converted to/from an `int *` is a really dangerous issue with c, one of many that are just waiting to catch out an inexperienced developer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way should be calling `qsort()`.

```
/* for strcmp() */
#include <string.h>
/* for qsort() */
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmpShift(const void* lhs, const void* rhs)
{
    return strcmp(((struct Shift*)lhs)->name, ((struct Shift*)rhs)->name);
}

void sort_data(struct Shift shift_data[], int *num_shifts)
{
    qsort(shift_data, *num_shifts, sizeof(struct Shift), cmpShift);
}
```

Comment: But perhaps the assignment is "write a sort function"...

Comment: No the assignment explicitly directs me to use these three functions I can add more but they must be included. I did not come up with this myself sorry for the flawed design.